# How to delete mounted folder to docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, volume

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myservice:
    build: .
    command: python -m main
    volumes:
      - /home:/home
```

I started `docker-compose up --build` and inside the project folder I see `/home` folder with a lock. How to remove it correctly? because I don't need it

[image]

Comment: Remove `volumes` section from docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: `sudo rm -rf home`?

Comment: @akop Yes, I can certainly delete this folder like that, but I had concerns that it might delete this folder in my file system.

Comment: Is that not what you want?

Comment: @akop I just don't know if suddenly deleting the home folder in the project will delete it unexpectedly on my filesystem. I made mount to this project

Comment: @akop I just don't understand very well how it works yet and the lock on the folder scares me a little)

Comment: Iam not sure what you want. Do you want that the lock will disappear or did you want to delete the folder? Or something else?

Comment: @akop I just want to delete this folder, but I don't know if it can delete my original folder - home

Comment: No, it is a other folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you  perhaps looking for something like [docker volume prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)?

> Remove all unused local volumes. Unused local volumes are those which are not referenced by any containers